# C# Dictionary include list as value, when list change, dictionary change

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I Created a Dictionary like this:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> MS = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

and Created a list like this:

```
List<string> Sig = new List<string>();
```

i need to read some strings by Sig, and add Sig to MS- the dictionary.
since there are different strings, after add Sig to MS, i clear Sig in order to read new strings,

```
 MS.Add(Mess1, Sig);
 Sig.Clear();
```

but when i clear Sig, the MS cleared too.
so what can i do? thanks a lot!

Comment: [How do I clone a generic list in C#?](//stackoverflow.com/q/222598)

Comment: Do you understand why this is happening?